# Symfony's Process PID increments by 1 during execution...?

Tags: php, symfony, process

I created a Symfony Command, which exports some data to file. Data are specific per user and my command receives userID as an argument. If userID is not specified, the command finds all users and then iterates through them, calling the same command for every user, but this time with user's ID:

```
// command execute():
$user = null;
$userId = $input->getOption('userId');
if($userId !== null)
    $user = // find user by ID in DB

if($user === null)
{
    // create $command and other arguments
    $users = // findAll()
    foreach($users as $user)
    { 
        // add user ID argument
        $returnCode = $command->run($argumentsInput, $output);
    }
}
else // do the export for specified user
```

More or less, that's how it works. Now, I want to call this command as background process from controller:

```
// controller action:
$process = new Process($command); //without userId
$processId = $process->getPid();
// save PID to file
```

And it almost works. Almost, because the PID changes. I'm guessing there's some child process started somewhere. As far as I see, the actual PID of the process that runs one command after another) is the `$processId + 1` and although everything else seems to work (one process calls commands, they work and export data), there's no process with `$processId`. 
I'm not going to assume it will always be `+1`, I just want to know, why it happens...?

Comment: Isn't it what `Process` is supposed to do? Run a new thread for each command?

Comment: @Stepashka I don't really care about the "child" threads PIDs here - I'm wondering, why Process that runs the "parent" command (and launches other commands) has different PID than obtained via getPid()...

Comment: On alpine linux it seems not to need +1